# Sharepoint multi-column validation

Tags: c#, validation, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got a custom list that contains multi collumns. The validation is made by a custom contenttype. Now I want a combination of two columns to be unique. Until know I did not found a way to solve this problem with on-board functions, so my idea was to use the eventreceiver or a customcontenttype.

What I tried:

**ListEventReceiver**

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {

           if (properties.AfterProperties["a1"].ToString() == properties.AfterProperties["a2"].ToString())
           {
               properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
               properties.Cancel = true;
               properties.ErrorMessage = "Failure";
           }
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
       }
```

It works fine, but the error message is not show as a validation error. It is a new errorpage.
[image]

**CustomContenttype**

If I try to validate in a custom contenttype I can not access the value of an other field from the contenttype. So I can not compare two fields or check they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validation using `ItemEventReceiver` than you should use `Sharepoint Error message page`.

its will so you better of your Errormessage.I have used it.

Like :

```
  if (properties.AfterProperties["a1"].ToString() == properties.AfterProperties["a2"].ToString())
       {
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
           properties.RedirectUrl = properties.WebUrl + "/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=Entry is Failure";
       }
```

or another way is Use [PreSaveAction](http://ghamson.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/useful-javascript-function-presaveaction-sp2010-sharepoint-ps2010-projectserver-in/) with javascript able to do valiation on list's forms.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the ValidationErrors, because this error would delete all the content inside the form and the user has to reenter the data.